# How would I fade out the edges of a plane, in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

So, I have a render I am working on. It has an ocean plane, and then since I don't want really long render times, there is a regular plane that extends out to 10km. I want this plane to fade out to transparent near the end so I have a nice transition to the horizon (sky texture)

How would I set up the nodes so I can get the edges of the plane to gradually fade out?

Answer (score 11):

You would just mix the main shader with a Transparent shader using a mix factor driven by a gradient texture.

[image]

Here's a slight expanded version with an ocean plane and adding a Dif/Glos shader to the ocean surface before blending in the transparency.

[image]

Comment: How it work with the texture. here i have the texture node setup. https://imgur.com/gallery/kWjFAqM